# Force (tension) is it relative or non-relative

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, string

Imagine a mass hanging from a string attached to the ceiling of a lift and the lift descends with a certain acceleration. From the reference frame of the ground the tension in the string would be smaller than when the lift remained stationery.

However, let's say your friend was inside the lift and when asked about the tension would say that the tension was same, regardless of the list ascending, descending or stationery.

Isn't that really counterintuitive? Isn't the force not relative and the same, regardless of the reference frame?

Comment: If your friend was standing on a scale watching its reading, he would know he is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend would not find that the tension is the same regardless of acceleration.  The tension would be acceleration dependent.  In your friend's accelerating reference frame, it would appear that the force of gravity is weaker than it is when the lift is stationary.  The tension would naturally be weaker, as it is the sole force opposing gravity on a mass that is stationary (in their frame).

The ultimate extreme version of this is to replace the lift with something like the [Vomit Comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced-gravity_aircraft), which climbs to a great height and then begins pitching over towards the ground, following a parabolic path.  This means its downward acceleration is exactly equal to the acceleration from gravity.  In your friend's reference frame on this plane, the force of gravity is zero (completely canceled out by the acceleration of the frame), and your friend is in free fall.  In this case, all observers would agree that the tension in the string is zero.

If you get into relativistic physics, you will find that we talk about such elevators and how the equations describing motion appear to be the same in all of them.  However, if you look at the wording carefully, we'll be speaking of "inertial reference frames," which are frames that are not accelerating nor decelerating.  Your elevator is accelerating, so it is not one of these cases.  Due to the acceleration of your elevator, you will indeed observe effects which distinguish it from a stationary elevator, from the perspective of all observers.